# DISTINCT ON in subquery by SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, distinct-on

I have a problem with query by ORM SQLAlchemy.

I need to write **subquery** like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.type) e.type AS e_type, e.num AS e_num 
FROM e ORDER BY e.type
```

by ORM SQLAlchemy, but when I've used `.subquery().alias("q")` in my query, `DISTINCT ON` was compiled to `DISTINCT`. Why and how am I fix it?

---

**Without .subquery()**:

```
db.session.query(E.type, E.num).distinct(E.type).order_by(E.type)
```

compile to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.type) e.type AS e_type, e.num AS e_num FROM e ORDER BY e.type
```

**With .subquery()**:

```
db.session.query(E.type, E.num).distinct(E.type).order_by(E.type).subquery().alias("q")
```

compile to

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.type AS e_type, e.num AS e_num FROM e ORDER BY e.type
```

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about how you have compiled and verified the result?

Comment: @IljaEverilä Well, I've seen query in debug watcher. For verify, I executed the simple SQL query `SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.type) e.type, e.num FROM e ORDER BY e.type` to database directly and got 50 rows, but in script query 78251 rows was got.